# Python PIL image Verify returns None

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am developing a tool which retrieves a JPG from an API and processes it. The source of the image cannot be trusted and I want to test if the image is a valid JPG (which is the only image type allowed).

I encountered an error with PIL that I am unable to fix. Below is my code:

```
image = StringIO(base64.b64decode(download['file']))
img = Image.open(image)
if img.verify():
    print 'Valid image'
else:
    print 'Invalid image'
```

However, it seems that img.verify() returns None. I can call other functions on the open image like img.size() which returns the size. I get the following output when I try to debug the code:

```
img = Image.open(image)
print img
print img.size()
print img.verify()

[2018-01-09 20:56:43,715: WARNING/Worker-1] <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=2577x1715 at 0x7F16E17DC9D0>
[2018-01-09 20:56:43,716: WARNING/Worker-1] (2577, 1715)
[2018-01-09 20:56:43,716: WARNING/Worker-1] None
```

Has someone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the docs, [Image#verify](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.verify) (or the [PIL docs for verify](http://www.effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.verify)) raises an exception if there is a problem with the image and does nothing otherwise.

To use `#verify`, you probably want something like this:

```
image = StringIO(base64.b64decode(download['file']))
img = Image.open(image)
try:
    img.verify()
    print('Valid image')
except Exception:
    print('Invalid image')
```

Additionally, you might want to also check that the image is actually a JPG by looking at the [image format](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.0.0/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.format):

```
if img.format == 'JPEG':
     print('JPEG image')
else:
     print('Invalid image type')
```

Comment: Ah, ok. I did read the docs but I thought that it would return something "usefull" like true of false. So None is the response to be expected?

Also, thanks for the img.format check.

Comment: Apparently `verify` atm is only implemented for PNG. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3012#issuecomment-368219545

Comment: it only verify the CRC.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `verify` and checking the `.format` field, if you're loading images from untrustworthy (and possibly genuinely malicious) sources over the web, you should worry about [zip bombs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb).

Pillow (but not, I think, original PIL) has a `DecompressionBombWarning` which is triggered when an image tries to exceed `Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS` (a value you can set yourself, prior to attempting to load an image).  The default value of that, on my install, is a very generous 85 Mpixels.

A fuller discussion about this Pillow feature is at [this discussion](https://github.com/zimeon/iiif/issues/11).