# Flask-Uploads: how to enforce file type by content (not just extension)

Tags: python, flask, flask-uploads

I am using Flask-Uploads to handle image uploading in a web app. The web app only accepts JPEG images but it seems that Flask-Uploads only enforces this by inspecting the file extension.

For example, I can easily subvert this by changing the file name from `myfile.txt` to `myfile.jpg` and the text file `myfile.txt` will be wrongly accepted as a JPEG image.

How do I ensure that files uploaded to my web app are in fact JPEG files by content, and not just by file extension?

Here is a minimal implementation (excluding templates) that demos what I am trying to do:

```py
# __init__.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_uploads import UploadSet, configure_uploads, IMAGES
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

photos = UploadSet("photos", IMAGES)
configure_uploads(app, photos)

from app import routes
```

```py
# routes.py

import os
from flask import redirect, render_template, send_from_directory, url_for
from flask_uploads import UploadNotAllowed
from app import app, photos
from app.forms import PhotoForm


@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = PhotoForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            filename = photos.save(form.photo.data)
            return redirect(url_for("uploaded_file", filename=filename))
        except UploadNotAllowed:
            print("UploadNotAllowed!")
            redirect(url_for("index"))
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)


@app.route("/uploads/<filename>")
def uploaded_file(filename):
    directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), app.config["UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST"])
    return send_from_directory(directory, filename)
```

```py
# forms.py

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.file import FileField, FileRequired
from wtforms import SubmitField


class PhotoForm(FlaskForm):
    photo = FileField(validators=[FileRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField("Upload")
```

```py
# config.py

import os


class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY")
    UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DEST = "uploads"
    UPLOADED_PHOTOS_DENY = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "svg"]
```

Comment: You'll need to use another library for this.  [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48178294/2052575) of what you wish to do, using `pillow`

Comment: I ended up doing this, but I thought I was overlooking an inbuilt way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could import `UploadSet` and - as described in the docstring - override the `file_allowed` method, by e.g. creating your own class, inheriting from `UploadSet`.

Then, you can choose one of several Python libraries, which can detect the type, e.g. https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic

P.S.: `Flask-Uploads` is broken since February 2020, at least the PyPi package.
I created a fork, which is a drop-in replacement and available via https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/